# How to tell VSCode which suggested "import" is correct for library creators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, package

As a library creator, I see that VSCode suggests bad imports to people.

For example, this is always suggested by VSCode:

```js
import useTranslation from 'next-translate/lib/esm/useTranslation'
```

However the correct that it should suggest is:

```js
import useTranslation from 'next-translate/useTranslation'
```

This is happening because the package is returning ESM or CJS, with this `package.json`:

```json
{
  "internal": true,
  "main": "../lib/cjs/useTranslation.js",
  "module": "../lib/esm/useTranslation.js",
  "types": "../lib/esm/useTranslation.d.ts"
}
```

Link to the generated package: https://www.runpkg.com/?next-translate@1.0.0-canary.3/useTranslation/package.json

Is there a way to tell VSCode or other editors/IDE what "import" should suggest?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have seen that the auto-import is related to where the TypeScript types are. **Moving the types to the root** solves it.

Instead of:

```json
{
  "internal": true,
  "main": "../lib/cjs/useTranslation.js",
  "module": "../lib/esm/useTranslation.js",
  "types": "../lib/esm/useTranslation.d.ts"
}
```

Doing this (After moving the types to the root):

```json
{
  "internal": true,
  "main": "../lib/cjs/useTranslation.js",
  "module": "../lib/esm/useTranslation.js",
  "types": "../useTranslation.d.ts"
}
```

Solve the problem.

Solved package: https://www.runpkg.com/?next-translate@1.0.0-canary.7/useTranslation/package.json